# Time elapsed since first log for each user

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I'm trying to calculate the time difference between all the logs of a user and the first log of that same user. There are users with several logs.

The dataframe looks like this:

```
16  00000021601     2022-08-23 17:12:04
20  00000021601     2022-08-23 17:12:04
21  00000031313     2022-10-22 11:16:57
22  00000031313     2022-10-22 12:16:44
23  00000031313     2022-10-22 14:39:07
24  00000065137     2022-05-06 11:51:33
25  00000065137     2022-05-06 11:51:33
```

I know that I could do `df['DELTA'] = df.groupby('ID')['DATE'].shift(-1) - df['DATE']` to get the difference between consecutive dates for each user, but since something like `iat[0]` doesn't work in this case I don't know how to get the difference in relation to the first date.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```py
import pandas as pd

dates = ['2022-08-23 17:12:04',
         '2022-08-23 17:12:04',
         '2022-10-22 11:16:57',
         '2022-10-22 12:16:44',
         '2022-10-22 14:39:07',
         '2022-05-06 11:51:33',
         '2022-05-06 11:51:33',]
ids = [1,1,1,2,2,2,2]
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':ids, 'dates':dates})
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'])
df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x['dates'] - x.iloc[0, 0])
```

```
Out:
id   
1   0       0 days 00:00:00
    1       0 days 00:00:00
    2      59 days 18:04:53
2   3       0 days 00:00:00
    4       0 days 02:22:23
    5   -170 days +23:34:49
    6   -170 days +23:34:49
Name: dates, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

If you dataframe is large and `apply` took a long time you can try use [parallel-pandas](https://pypi.org/project/parallel-pandas/). It's very simple

```py
import pandas as pd
from parallel_pandas import ParallelPandas

ParallelPandas.initialize(n_cpu=8)

dates = ['2022-08-23 17:12:04',
         '2022-08-23 17:12:04',
         '2022-10-22 11:16:57',
         '2022-10-22 12:16:44',
         '2022-10-22 14:39:07',
         '2022-05-06 11:51:33',
         '2022-05-06 11:51:33',]
ids = [1,1,1,2,2,2,2]
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':ids, 'dates':dates})
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'])
#p_apply is parallel analogue of apply method
df.groupby('id').p_apply(lambda x: x['dates'] - x.iloc[0, 0])
```

It will be 5-10 time faster

Comment: The dataframe is big and it's taking a long time to run. Is there any way to do it faster like the way I showed in the question? This "iloc[0, 0]" has two zeroes because the dataframe has to columns right?

Comment: I'm trying to do ```df['DELTA'] = df.groupby('ID')['DATE'].loc[0] - df['DATE']``` but I'm getting ```AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'loc'```

Comment: x.iloc[0,0] because first 0 is first row and seconds 0 means column with date.